# Please choose the bosh deployment

Tags: cloud-foundry, cf-bosh

I am working on bosh deployment deletion script

I follow following step

```
bosh -u $BOSH_USERNAME -p $COMMON_PASSWORD target $BOSH_PRIVATE_IP

bosh login $BOSH_USERNAME $COMMON_PASSWORD

bosh -n delete deployment cf-$SUBDOMAIN --force
```

Upto this point it works fine

```
cd /opt/myexample/installer/tenant-$SUBDOMAIN/deployments
```

This folder contain 
micro01/bosh_micro_deploy.log
micro01/micro_bosh.rb
micro01/micro_bosh.yml

```
`bosh -n micro delete`
```

Please choose the deployment

I get this error randomly.some time i get this error other time it works like a charm.
For work around I delete bosh director using nova command
Nova delete bosh_director id

Is this correct to delete like this ?
Am I missing something here.What is the correct way to delete bosh deployment ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `bosh micro deployment micro01/micro_bosh.yml` before `bosh micro delete`.